# Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T[]>'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm learning how to use `AngularFirebase` and I'm facing the issue which is the title.

Here is the code :

```js
  @Injectable()
  export class AbstractService<T> {

    constructor(private dbRef: AngularFireDatabase,
                private afAuthRef: AngularFireAuth,
                private dbFireStoreRef: AngularFirestore,
                private storageRef: AngularFireStorage,
                private message: MessageService) {
      this.dbRealTime = dbRef;
      this.afAuth = afAuthRef;
      this.dbFireStore = dbFireStoreRef;
      this.storage = storageRef;
    }

    <-- some other methodes -->

    getAll(path: string): Observable<T[]> {
      return this.dbRealTime.list(path).valueChanges();
    }
  }
```

And the other part is

```js
  export class BooksService extends AbstractService<Book> {

    addBook(book: Book) {
      return new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
          this.dbRealTime.list(this.suffixes.books).push(book).then(
            () => resolve(),
            (error) => reject(error));
        });
    }

    getAllBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
      return this.getAll(this.suffixes.books);
    }

  }
```

and yet I don't understand why I' having this error:

```
 ERROR in src/app/common/services/abstract.service.ts(59,5): error TS2322: 
 Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T[]>'.
 Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
 Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

I already tried others issues here on `StackOverflow` like placing `<T[]>` between the method and the parenthesis to cast the response ( or event after and before) without success.

Thank you for reading and I hope you'll help.

Comment: Create stackblitz

Comment: I don't know how to use `stackblitz`

Comment: Then learn how to use it then (Laziness level over 50000!). You can even import your whole project (and later on strip it down) https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Comment: Yeah ! I was already looking for it. So I'll just post when I'll finish

Comment: This likely means that valueChanges doesn't return expected type. It possibly should be `this.dbRealTime.list(path).valueChanges<Book>()` or `this.dbRealTime.list(path).valueChanges() as Observable<Book[]>`